# Orchard TagBuilderExtensions - Getting classes assigned to model

Tags: orchardcms

I'm trying to work with the grid.cshtml alternate in my theme and need to check if a certain class has been added to the grid through the layout editor, is there a way to either iterate or check against the classes that are assigned to the model?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can access the classes through the model by doing this in Grid.cshtml (and probably all other elements):

```
@{
    IEnumerable<string> classes = Model.Classes;
    var hasMyClass = classes.Contains("myClass");
}

@if (hasMyClass) {
    <h1>This Grid has css class 'myClass'!!</h1>
}
```